# input text not appearing in outlook

Tags: java, email

I am creating a velocity template vm with input type text and sending the email to outlook

Code: *.vm

```
    <table class="claim" cellpadding="7">
        <tr>
          <td>TAT compliance</td>
          <td>24 Hours</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Second opinion request raised by</td>
          <td>Ramesh Kumar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Reason for raising second opinion</td>
          <td>
            <input style="height:150px;width:300px;" name="body" id="ta1" type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

When it appears in outlook as

[image]

Can I know what could be the problem why the input box is not appear in mail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use input text box in Outlook mail body !

Comment: Can I know how can i get a input text box in mail box. For example google form